# Pre-generate java class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I seen in several videos that some people were creating classes whose content is generated automatically (eg a render method, create window, log, ...). How I can do this in eclipse?

Comment: For some tips how to use eclipse more effective you can take a look to this article: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-dont-write-c.

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a class, the Source menu has a lot of items that can generate content automatically.

[image]

Comment: But these methods are generated when you create the class

Comment: Yes, you need to create the class first, but the generate a lot of the mindless code you need to fill the class.  I thought that was what you are looking for.

Comment: Not really, for example, New > Class > Name > Finish. When you press finish, your class is generated with your own methods.